# Simple question, what does "n.g." stands for?

Tags: notation, terminology

I am ashamed about this question, I did seek for its meaning, but nothing to help.

I am checking a method of calculation of some sheet from a Technical Manual of engineering, and, I find this: "n.g.", contrary to "OK" for results of calculus.

Please help me, about its meaning; I'm sorry for my ignorance.

[image]

Comment: Never seen it in 25 years in the profession.

Comment: I've never seen it either.  "no good"?  Maybe an example of its use would clarify.

Comment: @lulu I added an excerpt of the manual.

Comment: Yes, probably not a math.SE question.

Comment: I'm sticking with "no good".  In the instance where it is used, we get a number which exceeds the grade of the plate, hence it is "no good".  In the other instance we get a number which is below the grade of the plate, hence it is "ok".

Comment: Your illustration shows a value of  $f_{max}$ in excess of $50$ ksi marked n.g. and a value below $50$ ksi marked O.k.  It seems in context to mean "no good" as @lulu suggests.

Comment: maybe “not (safety) guaranteed”

Comment: no go ; not good ; chinese /japanese usage

Comment: @Narasimham Is this usual in those countries? Because the report where I found is from US.

Comment: May be,  I use the same google . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that acronym is referring to the fact that the tension in the material is greater than the strength thus the acronym could be “(safely) not guaranteed” or something similar as observed in the comments.

Comment: Gimusi.Formidable!+++

Comment: Thanks Peter :)